# Dependency Injection to Unit of Work

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm having an issue my unitofwork doesn't create instance of AppSettings whenever it is called. Unitofwork is for my repository data layer.

This error comes out:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object. Core.UnitOfWork..ctor() in UnitOfWork.cs, line 24
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. Core.UnitOfWork..ctor() in
>   UnitOfWork.cs
>   +
>               _connection = new SqlConnection(App.GetConnectionString());
>   Core.Service.UserService.Login(User entity) in UserService.cs
>   +
>               using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(/*connStr*/)) SRTManagement.Controllers.LoginController+d__6.MoveNext() in
>   LoginController.cs
>   +
>                   var _user = service.Login(user);

Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IAppSettings,AppSettings>();
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

IAppSettings.cs

```
namespace Core.Etc
{
    public interface IAppSettings
    {
        string GetConnectionString();
    }
}
```

AppSettings.cs

```
namespace Core.Etc
{
    public class AppSettings : IAppSettings
    {
        public readonly string _connectionString;

        public AppSettings(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        }

        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return _connectionString;
        }
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork.cs

```
namespace Core
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private IDbConnection _connection;
        private IDbTransaction _transaction;
        private IUserRepository _user;
        private IRoleRepository _role;
        private IAppSettings App;
        private bool _disposed;
        private bool _token;

        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            _connection = new SqlConnection(App.GetConnectionString());
            _connection.Open();
            _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
            _token = false;
        }

        public IUserRepository UserRepository
        {
            get { return _user ?? (_user = new UserRepository(_transaction)); }
        }

        public IRoleRepository RoleRepository
        {
            get { return _role ?? (_role = new RoleRepository(_transaction)); }
        }

        public bool Success()
        {
            return _token;
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            try
            {
                _transaction.Commit();
                _token = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                _transaction.Rollback();
                _token = false;
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                _transaction.Dispose();
                _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
                ResetRepositories();
            }
        }

        private void ResetRepositories()
        {
            _user = null;
            _role = null;
            App = null;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            DisposeConn(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private void DisposeConn(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if(_transaction != null)
                    {
                        _transaction.Dispose();
                        _transaction = null;
                    }
                    if(_connection != null)
                    {
                        _connection.Dispose();
                        _connection = null;
                    }
                }
                _disposed = true;
            }
        }

        ~UnitOfWork()
        {
            DisposeConn(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you add breakpoint to this line `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");` what is the config returning?

Comment: @JohanP, sadly it doesn't hit the breakpoint. I'm not sure what i'm missing though.

Comment: Do you have `Startup` constructor?

Comment: I usually have `.AddMvc` first, then do my other DI registrations. So maybe try `services.AddMvc(); services.AddTransient<IAppSettings,AppSettings>();`

Comment: Yes @JohanP, I do have constructor in `Startup`

Comment: You're not injecting `IAppSettings` into your `UnitOfWork` constructor.  It's never initialized therefore is null.

Comment: Just tried adding `services.AddMvc();` before `services.AddTransient<IAppSettings,AppSettings>();` , breakpoint still doesn't hit `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IAppSettings` is not being injected into your `UnitOfWork`, so it will be null when call as you have it

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {
    private IDbConnection _connection;
    private IDbTransaction _transaction;
    private IUserRepository _user;
    private IRoleRepository _role;
    private IAppSettings App;
    private bool _disposed;
    private bool _token;

    public UnitOfWork(IAppSettings App) {
        this.App = App;
        _connection = new SqlConnection(App.GetConnectionString());
        _connection.Open();
        _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
        _token = false;
    }
    //Remove the rest of the code for brevity
}
```

Assuming `UnitOfWork` is also registered with the service collection.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddTransient<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

I would also suggest rethinking the current design and avoid tightly coupling the UoW to implementation concerns like `SqlConnection`.

If staying with ADO then consider using a `IDbConnectionFactory` abstraction.

```
public class MyDbConnectionFactory : IDbConnectionFactory {
    private readonly IAppSettings appSettings;

    public MyDbConnectionFactory(IAppSettings appSettings) {
        this.appSettings = appSettings;
    }

    public IDbConnection CreateConnection() {
        return new SqlConnection(appSettings.GetConnectionString());
    }
}
```

Which would let the UoW to be refactored to

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork {
    private IDbConnection _connection;
    private IDbTransaction _transaction;
    private IUserRepository _user;
    private IRoleRepository _role;
    private bool _disposed;
    private bool _token;

    public UnitOfWork(IDbConnectionFactory factory) {
        _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        _connection.Open();
        _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction();
        _token = false;
    }

    //Remove the rest of the code for brevity
}
```

With usual service registrations

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddTransient<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();
    services.AddTransient<IDbConnectionFactory, MyDbConnectionFactory>();
    services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: I'm using Dapper not ADO, the problem with current design is I need to create new UoW instance and pass connection string from my service layer. That's why I thought DI was a great idea to create UoW instance without need hardcoded connection string.

Comment: And I agree. That is not the problem. Dapper is being used on top of ADO anyway. Your UoW was not getting its desired dependencies. which is why you got the NRE.

Comment: Actually.. you're correct about that. Also I need to plan out new design, it will be hard for me to maintain in future with this design.